# Trying to get property of non-object error using get_post_meta()

Tags: post-meta

I made a simple function for post_meta, in `functions.php`:

```
// Top Sub Heading (top_sub) FROM CUSTOM FIELD
function topSub( $Trunckvalue = null ) {
    global $post;
    $TopSub = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'top_sub', $single=true );
    $shortTopSub = trunck_string( $TopSub, $Trunckvalue, true );
    if ( !$TopSub == NULL  ) { ?>
        <h3 class="top-sub"><?php echo $shortTopSub; ?></h3> <!-- .top-sub -->
    <?php }
    return $shortTopSub;
}

add_action( 'init', 'topSub' );
```

And in my theme I'm using it like: `topSub(300);`. Here, `trunck_string()` is another acting function - no need to worry about it.

The function is working fine. But with `WP_DEBUG` **true** - it's showing error:

> **Notice: Trying to get property of non-object  ... line 88**

And in line#88 resides:

```
$TopSub = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'top_sub', $single=true );
```

I used this many times, but this time, I'm getting error. What's wrong with my code?

For your kind information: `top_sub` is an optional custom field. There can be many *blank* custom fields on `top_sub` and there can be many *filled*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$post` is never set on `init` when I test this--

```
function topSub( $Trunckvalue = null ) {
    global $post;
    var_dump($post);
}
add_action( 'init', 'topSub' );
```

The earliest hook I can find (by experimentation, not a canonical statement) is `wp`.

Aditionally, `$post` is set on archive pages as well as "single" pages. On those archive pages it is set to the first post in the Loop.

The self-answer by @MayeenulIslam has a comment that ...

```
//check if post is object otherwise you're not in singular post
```

That statement is false.

I do not expect the code, or the self-answer, to work as expected for both of those reasons. The solution, by my reading should be:

```
// Top Sub Heading (top_sub) FROM CUSTOM FIELD
function topSub( $Trunckvalue = null ) {
    if (!is_singular()) return;
    global $post;
    $TopSub = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'top_sub', $single=true );
    $shortTopSub = trunck_string( $TopSub, $Trunckvalue, true );
    if ( !$TopSub == NULL  ) { ?>
        <h3 class="top-sub"><?php echo $shortTopSub; ?></h3> <!-- .top-sub -->
    <?php }
    return $shortTopSub;
}

add_action( 'wp', 'topSub' ); // or a later hook depending on circumstances
```

I am also puzzled by this line:

```
if ( !$TopSub == NULL  ) { ?>
```

You are checking whether `$TopSub` is not `NULL` but are actually using `$shortTopSub` in the conditional. It seems to me that that should be rewritten:

```
if ( !empty($shortTopSub) ) { ?>
    <h3 class="top-sub"><?php echo $shortTopSub; ?></h3> <!-- .top-sub -->
<?php }
```

Comment: Yes, `wp` is earliest for `$post` global since it is setup (if viable) by `WP->register_globals()` which runs right before that hook.

Comment: Thanks @Rarst. I didn't have time to look into it in much detail.

Comment: The top portion is quite interesting for me. Thanks a lot. But the bottom part - not surprising. The `$shortTopSub` is nothing but the truncked value of `$TopSub`. So checking whether `$TopSub` or `$shortTopSub` is theoretically same. Anyway, thanks for the nice critics. I'll check that and let you know.

Comment: I don't know what the `trunck_string` function does but were it to fail-- return an error object, for example-- the following code would not work correctly. It is just bad habit to check one value and then use some other derived value. The variables are not the same, theoretically or otherwise.

Comment: Thanks @s_ha_dum. Actually my `trunck_string()` function is to control the amount of words in a function (i.e. `my_excerpt(25)` will show 25 words most. It's ok. I always love to be with the good practice, and today I tried your suggestion, and you are right. Thanks for the nice criticism. Marked your one is accepted. :)

Answer (score 3):

Got the answer from:
» [**Trying to get property of non-object** - themeforest.net](http://themeforest.net/forums/thread/trying-to-get-property-of-nonobject-in-wordpress-help-/101783):

Check the variable `$post` is an object or not:

```
    global $post;

    //check if post is object otherwise you're not in singular post
    if( !is_object($post) ) 
        return;

    $TopSub = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'top_sub', $single=true );
```

- Function used in WordPress: [**Reference^**](http://doc-wordpress.com/nav.html?_functions/index.html).
- It's a PHP function: [`is_object`^](http://doc-wordpress.com/nav.html?_functions/index.html) in php.net

> **`is_object`** — Finds whether a variable is an object